# Create a fluid sidebar that expands to meet the edge of a center element

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

```css
aside {
  height: 80%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #0ee;
  opacity: 0.25;
  outline: 2px #0bb solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/rzPvQx.css">
    <title>grid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      width="100" height="100" class="cntr" id="grid"  
    >
      <script xlink:href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/rzPvQx.js"></script>
      
      <text 
        x="50" y="95"
        alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"
        class="title" 
      >SVG GRID</text>
      
      <g id="drwing">   
        <circle cx="60" cy="40" r="0.5" fill="#0cc" opacity="0.9" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    
    <aside></aside> <!-- the relevant element -->
    
    <script src="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/LjqmML.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would we make the `aside` element in the snippet above ( colored in aqua ) take up exactly the space in-between the right edge of the grid and the right edge of the browser window?

The left edge of the `aside` element should exactly touch the right edge of the grid. The right edge of the `aside` element should extend to the very end of the browser window ( on the *right* side ).

**Responsive:** Keep in mind the `aside` element needs to be responsive and both the left and right edges of this element need to stay at the right edge of the grid and right edge of the browser window respectively regardless of the width of the browser window.

*In other words we just need to stretch the `aside` element precisely from the grid to the end of the window no matter the browser dimensions.*

Giving the element this CSS:

```
aside {
  height: 80%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #0ee;
  opacity: 0.25;
  outline: 2px #0bb solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```

unfortunately does not work as the element obviously isn't touching the edges and translates in the `x` direction incorrectly when the window is resized. Any ideas?

*Please view the snippet at the top of the page in full screen and resize the window's width to see the incorrect behavior explained above.*

**Example of intended behavior:**
[image]

Comment: This would be way easier if you wrapped the SVG and the `aside` in an element. That an option?

Comment: @cjl750 That is an option as long as it doesn't interfere with the SVG's positioning. We could also wrap the aside element and a div element the same size as the SVG and absolutely position a parent wrapper if this helps preserve the positioning of the original SVG. What is the technique you have in mind?

Comment: I think a `calc()` function here will do you nicely and make more sense. Is the SVG supposed to be horizontally centered within the page, I guess?

Comment: @cjl750 Yeah, the grid is stuck in the center both horizontally and vertically regardless of the dimensions. Grid stays in the center and this `aside` div is eventually supposed to house controls up to a certain width until it pops on top. The idea is for the controls to stay centered between the grid and right browser edge though.

Comment: You could use flex and a pseudo element https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjdEge

Comment: @G-Cyr That's a great effort but the behavior of the grid has now changed aswell. The grid shrinks when it is supposed to keep dimensions until a given aspect ratio. *Grid should keep its exact same sizing and positioning behavior*. Is it possible to use this technique without that side-effect?

Comment: Since the grid script create an absolute positioned wrapper around the `svg` and adjust the size based on the viewport size, you'll need a script that get that wrappers size and position.

Comment: @LGSon *fredrivett* came up with a great CSS solution.

Comment: Actually, the nice thing about flex is that you do not have to mind the size of your svg(or any center element ) It works for any size. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WEPPVG My first codepen example had to deal and overwrite some of your CSS rules and javascript  already linked , it is maybe why you didn't catch how easy it is via flex ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr You put a lot of work into that and it conveys the concepts a lot better than the first pen :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it out of the flow, then one option is to use a "magic number". A magic number is where you use a hardcoded specific value that "just works". It's fragile, but sometimes it's necessary.

For this, the grid is 10rem wide. So you could do this:

```
aside {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: calc(50vw - 5rem); /* half width - 10rem / 2 */
}
```

Edit: [Here's a jsfiddle to show it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/5txbexc3/)

Comment: What about the edges of the aside matching up with the grid and browser window edge?

Comment: If the grid is set to a fixed width (10rem) then this will take that into account (the left side is 50% from the left (so in the middle) + half the width of the grid, so it'll align up). It's not tidy but it should work there. If it doesn't work on other breakpoints we can look at solving that too.

Comment: Thanks you for your interest in this question. Trying out this code in various ways but fail to see how this solves the problem. Perhaps you could provide a snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure no worries. Have edited my answer with a jsfiddle showing it in action. Note you need to remove your horizontal transform as that messes with it.

Comment: Not bad. Not bad at all, and even without the use of JavaScript or excessive CSS. Great Job it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ak06dw42/1/

Comment: Glad it helps @basement! Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if you feel it does what you're after.